# Change showHeader using javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Is there a way to change the showHeader attribute in  tag using javascript ? I have a VF page that I want to show headers if accessed outside the console but in a console I want it without the headers and sidebar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have 2 options here. The first one is to use purely javascript.

```
//header
document.getElementById('AppBodyHeader').style.display = 'none';
//sidebar
document.getElementById('sidebarDiv').style.display = 'none';
```

Your second option is to do that directly into your controller itself.

```
public Boolean showHeader {get;set;}
public TestController(){
    if (blablabla) showHeader = true;
    else showHeader = false;
}
<apex:page controller="TestController" showHeader="{!showHeader}">
```

Answer (score 0):

can you do something like below?

```
        if(sforce.console.isInConsole()) { 
            sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/apex/CustomVFPage?inConsole=yes, true, 'Custom VF Page'); 
        }else{ 
            window.top.location.href = 'https://'+window.location.hostname+'/apex/CustomVFPage?inConsole=no; 
        }
```

I think, you don't have to do any extra processing on the page..this will automatically take care of displaying header or not when in console.